# py-execute-line sends the whole buffer to the python process

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

I started to play with python-mode in Emacs (latest Emacs, latest python-mode.el)

When I try to send of line of code to the process via py-execute-line or send function definition via py-execute-def-or-class, it grabs the whole buffers, saves it in a temporary file and sends exec(compile(open(some_temp_file_name).read()...) string for execution to the process.
My question is why does it has to be that way?
Why can't we just (comint-send-string proc string) to the process where the string is one line of code or a block (or at least avoid saving a temp file every time)?

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce with current trunk.

Please file a complete bug-report at:

https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues